# ROW_NUMBER() SQL 2005 Query return Nulls

Tags: sql-server-2005, row-number

I'm with some problems to compare data from two different periods of a table using `ROW_NUMBER()` in SQL Server 2005, because of the Nulls.

I would be glad if somebody can give me some help.

```
CREATE TABLE MOV (ID INT,DATE_TIMEID DATETIME,AMOUNT MONEY)

INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-04 00:00:00',    1238.75)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-05 00:00:00',    1220.75)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-05 00:00:00',    1000.50)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-06 00:00:00',    1111.25)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-06 00:00:00',    1065.25)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-07 00:00:00',    939.75)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-07 00:00:00',    1606.25)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-08 00:00:00',    1364.25)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-08 00:00:00',    2379.75)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-09 00:00:00',    908.25)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2011-01-09 00:00:00',    35.25)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1367, '2010-01-10 00:00:00',    1.50)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-04 00:00:00',    1164.80)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-05 00:00:00',    1385.50)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-06 00:00:00',    1683.90)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-07 00:00:00',    1420.80)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-08 00:00:00',    173.70) 
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-09 00:00:00',    117.50)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1368, '2010-01-10 00:00:00',    1052.20)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-03 00:00:00',    1052.20)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-04 00:00:00',    1164.80)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-05 00:00:00',    1385.50)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-06 00:00:00',    1683.90)
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-07 00:00:00',    1420.80)    
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-08 00:00:00',    173.70) 
INSERT INTO MOV (ID,DATE_TIMEID,AMOUNT)VALUES(1404, '2011-01-09 00:00:00',    117.50)
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT MOV1.ROWID,
       MOV1.ID,
       MOV1.DATE_TIMEID,
       MOV1.AMOUNT,
       MOV2.ROWID                    ROWID2,
       MOV2.ID                       ID2,
       MOV2.DATE_TIMEID              Date_timeID2,
       MOV2.AMOUNT                   Amount2,
       ( MOV1.AMOUNT - MOV2.AMOUNT ) Diff,
       CASE
         WHEN MOV1.AMOUNT = 0 THEN 0
         ELSE ( ( ( MOV1.AMOUNT - MOV2.AMOUNT ) * 100 ) / MOV1.AMOUNT )
       END                           AmountToPercent
from   (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN MOV.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE
               MOV.ID
                      END,
               CASE WHEN MOV.DATE_TIMEID IS NULL THEN '01/01/1900' ELSE
               MOV.DATE_TIMEID
                      END ASC
               )
               AS
                      'ROWID',
               CAST(MOV.ID as CHAR(4)) /*+ ' - ' + V_ParkingUserAccess.ParkingName*/
               ID,
               DATE_TIMEID,
               Sum(AMOUNT)
               AMOUNT
        from   dbo.MOV
        where  MOV.ID between 1367 and 1404
               and DATE_TIMEID >= '01/03/2011'
               and DATE_TIMEID <= '01/09/2011'
        group  by MOV.ID,
                  DATE_TIMEID) MOV1
       INNER JOIN (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MOV.ID, MOV.DATE_TIMEID
                          ASC) AS
                          'ROWID',
                          MOV.ID
                          ID,
                          DATE_TIMEID
                                                       DATE_TIMEID,
                          Sum(AMOUNT)
                                                       AMOUNT
                   from   dbo.MOV
                   where  MOV.ID between 1367 and 1404
                          and DATE_TIMEID >= '01/04/2010'
                          and DATE_TIMEID <= '01/10/2010'
                   group  by MOV.ID,
                             DATE_TIMEID) MOV2
         ON MOV1.ROWID = MOV2.ROWID
            and MOV1.ID = MOV2.ID
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: could you try to **reduce** this to the absolutely necessary minimum to show the problem you have?? This is just a HUMONGUOUS amount of code you're throwing at us here...... Also: your INSERT statement won't work - you need to put your DATETIME values into single quotes!  `'2010-01-05'` instead of  `2010-01-05`

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ROW_NUMBER()` **never** returns NULLs - there must be some other issue..... try to decompose your query into smaller, more manageable parts, and debug it to find out where the error comes from....

Comment: I fixed your `insert` statements and commented out the part about `V_ParkingUserAccess.ParkingName` as that refers to an object that isn't defined anywhere in the code you posted. I don't see any `NULL` s in either the OUTPUT or your example data.

Comment: Thank for the tips, the problem I have is when I execute the query because there Movements null to a period, the query just brings the results until the ID before the null mov starts. If I do an outer join brings the lines, but with nulls in every colunm including the row id and the the row id it is not correctly associated.

Comment: @user619355: Could you also post the result set as well? Then you would only need to point out what exactly was wrong with it. I mean, I've run your query on your kindly supplied example data, but there's no NULLs in the result set, so I cannot figure out what seems to be the problem.

Comment: The result is like that (sorry I didn't how to format that :( )ROWID ID DATE_TIMEID AMOUNT ROWID2 ID2 DATE_TIMEID2 AMOUNT2 Diff AmountToPercent 1 1367 4/01/2011 1238,75 1 1367 5/01/2010 1220,75 18 1,453 2 1367 5/01/2011 1000,5 2 1367 6/01/2010 1111,25 -110,75 -11,0694 3 1367 6/01/2011 1065,25 3 1367 7/01/2010 939,75 125,5 11,7812 4 1367 7/01/2011 1606,25 4 1367 8/01/2010 1364,25 242 15,0661 5 1367 8/01/2011 2379,75 5 1367 9/01/2010 908,25 1471,5 61,8342 6 1367 9/01/2011 35,25 6 1367 10/01/2010 1,5 33,75 95,7446 , the lines for the ID's 1368 and 1404 should be in the result

Comment: The ID 1368 has information for the year 2010 and 1404 has information for the year 2011, so they should appear in the result

Comment: @Kel: Oh, I meant adding it to your question post. I'm sorry, I should have made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Finally saw it.

Rows for `ID = 1367` contain date values from both date ranges of `01/03/2011..01/09/2011` and `01/04/2010..01/10/2010`. And so they get selected on both sides of the inner join, and the join takes place accordingly.

The other two have got either one date range or the other. Consequently one of the subselects returns no rows. And because it's an INNER join, you get no rows ultimately for those IDs.

Comment: Tks Andriy M, but the problem is I need to bring those other rows and if I use a full outer join the RowId gets crazy :(

Comment: @Kel: I think you need to add `PARTITION BY {some criteria, most probably ID, but not sure whether simply ID}` to both of your `ROW_NUMBER` definitions. Try it yourself first. When you need more help, please post a *new* question and state explicitly what kind of data you have got, i.e. how they are distinct from each other, why they cannot be selected with your current query and how they *should* be selected (which data goes to which columns). And also link it to this question so people could see that wasn't a duplicate.